# Change parameter name without breaking backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, backwards-compatibility, named-parameters

I am working on a c# library, so we are concerned with breaking backwards compatibility, but I was wondering is it possible to change just the name of a parameter and maintain backwards compatibility because of the ability to use named parameters? An example of what I am trying to do is below

```
[Obsolete("use ChangeSpecificFoo(SpecificFoo specificFoo)")]
public void ChangeSpecificFoo(SpecificFoo foo)
{
    _specificFoo = foo;
}

//Compile error ... already defines a member called 'ChangeSpecificFoo' with the same parameter types
public void ChangeSpecificFoo(SpecificFoo specificFoo)
{
    _specificFoo = specificFoo;
}
```

Just changing the parameter name runs the potential risk of breaking backwards compatibility because someone could be calling the method using named parameters like `ChangeSpecificFoo(foo: someSpecificFoo)` , but we can't deprecate the method by adding a new method with the correct parameter name because parameter names are not included in the method signature, so the compiler sees it as a duplicate.

Is there any way around this? The only alternatives I see are changing the method name so it is not a duplicate and then deprecating the old method, or waiting until we add or remove parameters from the parameter list and changing the parameter names then(this may never happen because the method is pretty stable), or just make the change and fix any breaks that we may have from code using this library as we find them.

Comment: Functionally, both of those methods are the exact same. Putting either one of them in your code would make no difference

Comment: @Plutonix: No, with named arguments changing the parameter name is a breaking change. Consider `ChangeSpecificFoo(foo: new SpecificFoo())`. That will compile with the first method but not the second.

Comment: @Andrew: That's not true, due to named arguments.

Comment: Ah, ok - I get it now

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand what you're saying, but now I'm wondering why it is like that? That seems like a dumb way to go about it...

Comment: @Andrew: A dumb way to go about what? It's not clear what you're criticising.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just mean what is the benefit to using named arguments if it runs the risk of breaking as above? What extra benefit/functionality would that provide?

Comment: @Andrew: A *massive* improvement in readability in various cases, where there are multiple parameters of the same type... and a huge increase in usefulness of optional parameters, as it allows any optional parameter to be specified.

Comment: I'd add/update the XML comment block to clarify

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll take your word for it, I'm just not very familiar with using named parameters.

Comment: @Andrew People changing the names of parameters for the sake of changing the names is a very minor concern. This really never happens in a real scenario, especially when you don't own all the code that will be calling your methods. As always, Jon Skeet named plenty of examples of the (potentially) rare cases when you would opt to use named parameters.

Comment: @krillgar Okay, makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first inclination for this is simple: **DON'T**. The name of your parameter is irrelevant outside of the method body. You're right to consider people calling it out by name, and therefore potentially breaking it. However, just changing the name of the parameter gives no real benefit.

The only possible reason for changing the name is to redefine what the method does because the old name leads to confusion. In that case, the name of the method should also be changed in order to not introduce another form of confusion. (The fact that the method signatures are identical is the first and more important reason to not change parameter names. However, this is to potentially explain *why* you might want to.)

If however, you are still adamant about keeping the same method signature, but altering the name, you could do this. (Again, I'm strongly recommending you either don't change it at all, or rename the method as well to continue to eliminate confusion.)

One way around this would be to have the method with both parameters, but make the second optional. Have that last parameter use the old name, and then assign it over within the method.

I would also **HIGHLY** recommend logging any uses of the named parameter, to see if your concern is valid about people calling it as a named parameter.

```
public void ChangeSpecificFoo(SpecificFoo specificFoo = null, SpecificFoo foo = null)
{
    if (foo != null && specificFoo == null)
    {
        // Add any other details you can, especially 
        // to figure out who is calling this.
        Log("Someone used a name parameter!!");
    }
    _specificFoo = specificFoo ?? foo;
}
```

As [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) pointed out in the comments, this will not stop anyone from calling this method like so: `ChangeSpecificFoo(null, new SpecificFoo())`, which will trigger a logging.

His observation introduces another reason why this is a bad idea: You're now introducing ANOTHER way for people to "incorrectly" call your method. Therefore, I'll repeat my advice from the top of my answer: **DON'T** do this, unless you *really really really* need to change that parameter name.

Comment: Technically I can call, say `ChangeSpecificFoo(null, new Foo());` without using named parameters and this call will be logged named one.

Comment: Yeah, however then you'll also be logging that someone is calling this is a way that you don't want them to. I'll edit my answer to include that warning. No matter how you do it, this is a terrible idea. *But*, if you have that 0.0000001% edge case where you **really** need to do this, here is one idea.

Comment: To clarify, the reason we are looking to change the parameter name is almost entirely for internal maintenance. Obviously the example is an oversimplification, but to continue on that same example, we already have an object named Foo, so seeing a parameter floating around with the name of foo is confusing when really it is a SpecificFoo. What we may end up doing is renaming the parameter at the top of the method so that we don't have that confusion. If the confusion was in the naming of the method then we would just change the method name, but it already has the name that we want.

Comment: Yeah. If it's causing confusion with a member variable with that same name, then renaming the one that everyone else can't see is the way to go.